# How to do file type detection based on file contents (e.g. a certain shebang line)?

Tags: filetype, ftdetect

I have created a few scripts in `.vim/ftdetct` to e.g. detect the filetype of `sshconfig` files based on their filename:

`autocmd BufRead,BufNewFile ~/.ssh/host-* setfiletype sshconfig`

Now, how can I make Vim detect the filetype based on the shebang (`#!`) line in files, e.g.:

```
#!/usr/bin/awk -f
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If you want to introduce a file type and that file type can only be identified by examining the contents of such files then you'll need to add appropriate logic to a file named `scripts.vim`.

But first, let's take a step back and look at the bigger picture. (Skip to the "Solution" section, below, if you're not interested in the technical details.)

### Background

File type detection is enabled with the command `:filetype on`. (This is typically in the user vimrc file or triggered by sourcing `defaults.vim`.)

The command will cause Vim to source the script named `filetype.vim` found in the directory named in the `$VIMRUNTIME` environment variable. Doing so sets up a bunch of `au BufNewFile,BufRead` autocommands. Since detection by filename is much more common than detection by content, the bulk of `filetype.vim` is made up of lines like the following:

```
au BufNewFile,BufRead *.clj,*.cljs,*.cljx,*.cljc  setf clojure
```

A couple thousand lines later we get to the part that kicks off detection by content:

```
au BufNewFile,BufRead *
    \ if !did_filetype() && expand("<amatch>") !~ g:ft_ignore_pat
    \ | runtime! scripts.vim | endif
```

The `*` indicates that this autocommand will be triggered for all files so some logic is needed to filter out files that already matched a file extension specific autocommand (or otherwise had their type identified). `!did_filetype()` guards against this as the function returns true if the `FileType` event has been triggered at least once prior and we negate (`!`) the result, thus halting further execution of the line. (We'll be using this same function in a guard block in our `scripts.vim`.)

Following that is a check that the filename we're dealing with doesn't match certain extensions (e.g. `.zip`)

If those two checks are passed, `scripts.vim` will be executed. But which one? The [`:runtime`](https://vimhelp.org/repeat.txt.html#:runtime) command means that ALL files named `scripts.vim` appearing in one of the paths specified in [`'runtimepath'`](https://vimhelp.org/options.txt.html#%27runtimepath%27) will be sourced/executed. There is always an instance of this file in the `$VIMRUNTIME` directory. We're going to achieve our goal by creating our own instance of it.

Note that, by default, the first path in `'runtimepath'` is `$HOME/.vim` (or non-Unix equivalent). That's where our script file is going to go which means our detection logic will take precedence over that in `$VIMRUNTIME` or anywhere else.

(As an aside, a plugin-manager's main function is to update `'runtimepath'` and add a path for each installed plugin. While these typically get inserted before any system directories, as far as I know they always come after `$HOME/.vim`.)

### Solution

With the deep dive out of the way let's get down to business.

The standard place to put the local `scripts.vim` file is in your personal Vim folder (usually in `$HOME`) so run the following command (or your system equivalent): `vim ~/.vim/scripts.vim`

Assuming the file didn't exist before now, you'll want to add a guard block based on the function `did_filetype()` which we covered above. Follow that with a conditional block with appropriate detection logic. For the OP's use case that would look like this:

```
if did_filetype()   " filetype already set..
  finish        " ..don't do these checks
endif

if getline(1) =~ '^#!/usr/bin/awk -f'
  setfiletype yourfiletype
endif
```

If the file already existed there's presumably something like the above already in it. In that case just append your detection logic as an `elseif`.

```
" Existing two conditionals...
if {condition1}
  setfiletype filetype1
elseif {condition2}
  setfiletype filetype2
...etc...
" Add these two lines
elseif getline(1) =~ '^#!/usr/bin/awk -f'
  setfiletype yourfiletype
endif
```

See also [`:h new-filetype-scripts`](https://vimhelp.org/filetype.txt.html#new-filetype-scripts) and [`:h filetypes`](https://vimhelp.org/filetype.txt.html#filetypes)

Comment: Thanks. Didn't knew that. Is `scripts.vim` a special name? Could I choose any other name for the file? Would it be possible to add that code to a file in `ftdetect` to group all file-detection related files?

Comment: @BLayer You should probably include the explanation of `scripts.vim` (special filename, where it's searched for, runs with buffer loaded, etc.) as part of the answer...

Comment: @filbranden Fair enough.

Comment: The additions I made may convince you that you should stick with 'scripts.vim'.

Comment: @BLayer - Sure, sorry that I forgot

Comment: @Shuzheng No worries! Thanks. BTW, I added a lot of into to the answer after your last comment of 6/23. Not sure if you saw that so FYI.