# Can (Neo)Vim be configured to set the filetype according to the shebang?

Tags: neovim, filetype

Lately I've been using `neovim` to edit lots of files with the `.tmpl` extension. These files all have shebangs, most (but not all) of which are `#!/bin/sh`.

The default behavior seems to be that `neovim` opens these files with the `filetype` as `template`. I then have to issue `:set filetype=TYPE` where `TYPE` depends on the shebang. Is it possible to configure `neovim` to automate this behavior?

Comment: Maybe this question: [How to do file type detection based on file contents (e.g. a certain shebang line)?](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/31646/how-to-do-file-type-detection-based-on-file-contents-e-g-a-certain-shebang-lin) answer yours.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to do file type detection based on file contents (e.g. a certain shebang line)?](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/31646/how-to-do-file-type-detection-based-on-file-contents-e-g-a-certain-shebang-lin)

Comment: Just realizing that those can't be dupes: that answer requires that `!did_filetype()`, which won't be true here since a filetype was already set! So the correct solution depends on how `template` was set and/or using regular ftdetect to check the shebang.